# Is it possible to use onboard in TTY?

Tags: tty, onboard

I have old convertible netbook which is so weak even Lubuntu runs slow on it. I want to install Ubuntu Server (no GUI) and control it exclusively via tty.

Sometimes, I'd like to use the TTY in "converted" form, so I won't have access to my keyboard. Is there a way to get the `onboard` on-screen keyboard visible from the TTY?

Comment: As `onboard` is a graphical application, you won'tbe able to use it without a desktop (gnome, xfce, ..). And I don't think the touchscreen works without GUI.

Comment: If RAM is the limiting factor (too low RAM for Lubuntu to run well), the  following test might be relevant: It runs in a small system made from the Ubuntu 32-bit mini.iso, that is available as a compressed image file: 1) Running in text screen mode - used RAM=74 MiB; 2) Running in LXDE (simpler than Lubuntu) -  used RAM=105 MiB; 3) Running in LXDE with Onboard --  used RAM=127 MiB. It should still be possible this way if you have 512 MB RAM or more - enough margin for some application programs, but the margin is shrinking with every new program that needs RAM. It helps with 2GB swap.

Comment: The same system uses less RAM in a computer from 2008 (with an M2N-VM DVI mobo with AMD Athlon 64 X2 4400+). Running in text screen mode - used RAM=42 MiB; 2) Running in LXDE (simpler than Lubuntu) - used RAM=78 MiB; 3) Running in LXDE with Onboard -- used RAM=93 MiB. I am updating this and similar compressed image files, and I added onboard to this system (a 32-bit system will need less RAM than a 64-bit system, so it will work better where RAM is the limiting factor, and should work well in 64-bit computers, particularly if old or weak. See the links in the 'answer', that I will write soon.

Comment: You told us that kterm according to @kenn's answer does not work in text screen mode. If you find no other solution (and you need Onboard or a similar tool), you need at least a simple GUI, and it can be lighter than Lubuntu. And you can run in text screen mode except when you need Onboard.

Comment: Yeah, that's most probably the only solution, so I mark your answer as right, thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome, and I hope it will work well enough for you (uisng a GUI with an ultra light footprint). LXDE (by itself) is light. Using a window manager (not a full desktop environment) is even lighter. LXDE uses Openbox. There are also Fluxbox, JWM and some other window managers. `twm` comes from UNIX. It is old and very light, but might do the job in your particular case, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Start with an Ubuntu Server iso file or Ubuntu mini.iso

I would select a 32-bit system for an old or weak computer, even if the computer has a 64-bit system because a 32-bit system uses less RAM. But it is also possible to select a 64-bit system or try both and decide afterwards which is the best in your particular case.

After installing the basic system you can install a simple window manager like Openbox or Fluxbox, or plain LXDE (used in Lubuntu, but without the extra features of Lubuntu), Onboard, and *your* favourite application programs. It is possible to make the system boot into a text screen, and after that have the option to start the graphical user interface.

### Start with a compressed image of an installed 32-bit system

You can also download a compressed image file with an installed 32-bit system built from Ubuntu `mini.iso` and tweaked to be easy to manage in order to expand into different final systems.

This file is found at this link

[dd_X32-dus-lxde-Intl_2017-06-13_4GB.img.xz](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_X32-dus-lxde-Intl_2017-06-13_4GB.img.xz)

The md5sum is

```
4ad6c6477afc3dba4e6d266ca4bc4a6d  dd_X32-dus-lxde-Intl_2017-06-13_4GB.img.xz
```

and the file expands to 4 GB on the target drive, so you need a drive with at least 4 GB.

**Login and password**

```
user:     guru
password: changeme
```

Please change the password.

**Links describing the system**

The descriptions at the following links can help you install and use the system in the new compressed image file,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/OBI/Xenial-32-txt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OBI/Xenial-32-txt) (Xenial, the current version)

[UEFI-and-BIOS mini system with 'text' screen user interface](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#Mini_system_with_.27text.27_screen_user_interface) (the 64-bit version)

Text mode menu as seen after log in:

[image]

LXDE graphical desktop environment with Onboard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer, but as I said above, I want to control my PC exclusively via tty, I want no GUI.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source terminal emulator with embedded virtual keyboard. You can test it. Download and compile source code from  [here](https://github.com/bfabiszewski/kterm)
It's installed in `/usr/local/bin` by default.

And run it like

```
kterm -k 1 -l /usr/local/etc/kterm/layouts/keyboard.xml
```

**EDIT:** You will also need  mouse support in `tty` mode to use `kterm`.

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install gpm
```

EDIT2: Though it has been a long time after the question, I've found a working solution [here](https://github.com/zrafa/onscreenkeyboard).
First you need to enable framebuffer in your Linux installation.
Framebuffer provides lightweight graphical aid in your `tty`.

Clone this repository:

```
 git clone https://github.com/zrafa/onscreenkeyboard
 cd onscreenkeyboard
 make
 chmod +x ./osk
 sudo cp ./osk /usr/bin
```

then run it from your `tty`

For more info check out: https://github.com/zrafa/onscreenkeyboard

Comment: It doesn't run in tty